# Replies to "l'chayim"

Tags: minhag, blessing, chabad, provenance, liquor-beer

The most common responses I've heard to a wish of "*l'chayim!*" ("life!") is

- "*l'chayim tovim ulshalom*" ("a good life and peace!") *except* from Lubavitch *chasidim* and
- "*l'chayim v'livracha*" ("life and blessing!") from Lubavitch *chasidim*.

What is the provenance of and reason for each of these turns of phrase?

Comment: Inspired by http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1134.

Comment: Where does the whole "*l'chayim!*" thing come from in the first place?

Comment: @jake http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: The [_Taamei Haminhagim_](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&hilite=2b1fcacf-53fd-4b5f-b3e0-336977794585&st=%u05dc%u05d7%u05d9%u05d9%u05dd&pgnum=44) records that the _Chasam Sofer_ was _medayek_ not to say _"L'chaim Tovim"_ as a response since it is _b'gematria "klala"._ Instead he would say _"L'chaim v'l'vracha"._ Apparently, in his time there was a custom  to say only _"L'chaim Tovim",_ without _"ul'shalom"._ However at the top of that page he records the custom of saying _"L'chaim Tovim Ul'shalom."_

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33232/759

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, I wouldn't post just a quote, but it so perfectly addressed the question...

From [Hayom Yom (29th of first Adar)](http://www.lchaimweekly.com/cgi-bin/lessons.cgi?date=23032012&d2=1&Center=y&Java=y), written/compiled by the Lubavitcher Rebbe:

> In responding to L'chayim there are two versions:
>
> - L'chayim Tovim Ul'Shalom, "for good life, and for peace." The reason for this blessing is that the first time drinking wine is mentioned in the Torah, there were undesirable results. "Noach began etc."<sup>1</sup> also, the Tree of Knowledge was a grapevine.<sup>2</sup> Therefore we extend the blessing that this wine be for a good life.
> - The Maggid of Mezritch used to respond L'Chayim VeLivracha. Once at a Farbrengen, the Alter Rebbe responded L'Chayim VeLivracha. After the Farbrengen Chassidim discussed this expression, which they heard then for the first time.
>
> One chassid proposed: Since "When wine enters, the secret comes out,"<sup>3</sup> which in Avoda signifies that the emotions are revealed, we need a B'racha for this; the expression is L'Chayim VeLivracha, and "Livracha" may be read, Leiv Raka, a sensitive heart.
>
> The Tzemach Tzedek commented: Such an interpretation could be proposed only by a Chassid who has Davened and labored in Avoda for thirty years.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>1: Also translated as "Noach corrupted himself" or "profaned himself" or "degraded himself." Bereishit 9:20.</sup>
> <sup>2: See Tikunei Zohar, Tikun 24.</sup>
> <sup>3: Eiruvin 65a.</sup>

Comment: If you wanted an authoritative answer...... you got it!

Comment: Many thanks! +1 (and most likely, eventually, the checkmark). This answers my question completely except as to the provenance of _l'chayim tovim ulshalom_.

Comment: @msh210 I assume you're referring to the provenance of using that phrase _for this purpose_? Because the phrase itself is common in things like davening, and the reason for using such a phrase are explained by the Rebbe.

Comment: Yes, for this purpose.