# When does one say סברי or ברשות?

Tags: blessing

What are the boundaries for when one says סברי or ברשות before making a blessing?
(As an example, my siddur has סברי מרנן ורבנן ורבותי printed before the blessing of hagafen for kiddush.)

Comment: http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%93#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.97

Answer (score 1):

For סברי מרנן ורבנן ורבותי  see this question here:  [Source for pairing l'chaim with alcohol?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33232/source-for-pairing-lchaim-with-alcohol)
The key phrase is in the Midrash ([מדרש תנחומא פ' פקודי סי' ב'](http://kodesh.snunit.k12.il/tan/b0023.htm)) which says:

> כוס של קדוש או של הבדלה [והוא ירא מסם המות שלא יהיה בכוס], והוא אומר סברי מרנן, ואומר הקהל לחיים
>
> Over Kiddush or Havdalah [if one is afraid of poison in the cup], one says "Savri", and the people respond "L'chaim."

ברשות however, should be said, when you are being a host to a meal, and want to gain the permission of the people gathered to join you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the linked question doesn't answer exactly when סברי is said. Also, is ברשות only said over hamotzi or are there other food items it might be said over as well?

Comment: @Malper Read it again: Savri is only for wine - as per other question. Birshut is whenever you want to get everybody's attention; The equivalent of coughing or tinkling the cup with a fork.

Comment: @DannySchoemann The linked source does not make it clear that savri absolutely should not be said over other alcoholic beverages. With regards to birshut, can you provide a source for that claim, or is that just speculation?

Comment: @Malper  I'm not sure why you think the source does not answer the question... As for ברשות, it's custom, it doesn't matter what your 'meal' is over.

Comment: @Malper: You will not find a source "that savri absolutely should not be said over other alcoholic beverages" since it's not a Law - it's simply the "etymology" of Savri that was being discussed. Birshut: Speculation - here's a source, if you want: http://www.yahadoot.net/Answer.asp?id=298

Comment: [This](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/33236/3318) implies that savri shouldn't be said on other alcohol. You might want to add that to this answer.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Thanks for the link. If you can find a source for its claims in an actual sefer, it would much improve this answer.

Comment: @Malper, I'm not sure what you were linking to, but the answer that I saw the link go to, says at the end " He also mentions in the name of the Baal Shem Tov not to say L'Chaim on whiskey, only to say it on wine."

Comment: @avi Exactly, which implies that one wouldn't say savri on whiskey.

Comment: @Malper only wine. Not alchohol in general. And only wine during kiddush or havdalah.